# From where can I get all mathematical formatting syntaxes supported here?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

Looks like I can post mathematical notations here without glitch. I want to know all syntaxes for that. Is it documented? Is it all old Matlab?

Comment: It is LaTeX. ${}$

Comment: Maybe you can start [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: It should be answer... Thanks!

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official list of [macros supported by MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#supported-latex-commands) should tell you what macros you can use.  It also has a link to [examples of all macros](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) created by Carol Fisher that should be very helpful in understanding how to use them.  Carol's examples were written for v1.1, so there are a few items it doesn't document, but by-and-large it is pretty complete.

Comment: I think that list has been updated for 2.0.  For example, \middle was added i 2.0, and it is listed there.

Comment: I see that my statement was a bit ambiguous.  The first link (to the MathJax documentation) is the v2.0 list, as you point out.  The second link is the one that I meant was written for v1.1.  I have edited the answer to make that clearer (I hope).

Comment: Is there anything documenting the changes from 1.1 to 2.0, even if not at user-level? (e.g. a changelog).

Comment: See the [What's New in v2.0](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/whats-new-2.0.html) documentation page, and in particular the [TeX additions](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/whats-new-2.0.html#many-new-tex-additions-and-enhancements) and [Other Bug Fixes](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/whats-new-2.0.html#other-bug-fixes) sections.